# C++ Using Raw pointer to std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-ptr, race-condition

So I'm trying to pass a shared pointer between threads via a messaging mechanism that I'm using. Due to how the serialization/deserialization works, I cannot directly embed a shared_ptr into a message that I send. So I effectively need to send a raw pointer of a shared_ptr. See below:

Thread 1:

```
auto objPtr = std::make_shared<ObjectClass>();
uint64_t serializedPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&objPtr);
```

Thread 2:

```
std::shared_ptr<ObjectClass> objPtrT2 = *(reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<ObjectClass>*>(serializedPtr));
```

This sometimes crashes in thread 2 when it goes to increment the reference count of the shared pointer. I can only assume some race condition is at play here but haven't been able to sort out a solution. Note that it doesn't always crash and the deserialization is seemingly always successful.

Do I need to synchronize access to this shared_ptr (the shared_ptr itself, not what the share_ptr points to)? I'm concerned that the manner in which I am transferring this shared_ptr is breaking how the reference count is being managed.

I'm still debating whether the use of a shared_ptr is appropriate here for other performance related reasons but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong for my own benefit.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Just to note, thread 1 and thread 2 are in the same process/host. I am emplacing the shared_ptr into a map managed by thread1 (I tried to leave out details that I initially thought to be unimportant). What I didn't realize, however, was that the manner in which I retrieve from said map was incorrect. I was copying the contents of the map into a temp shared_ptr and then sending the address of the temp shared_ptr to thread2. So I was unwittingly sending over the address of a variable on the stack. Silly mistake, but I think the commentary in this thread has been quite instructive/helpful nonetheless. The following seems to fix my issue.

```
auto& objPtr = m_objMap[index];
uint64_t serializedPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&objPtr);
```

Comment: If the serialize pointer is the only one left, the `ObjectClass` will be destroyed. `shared_ptr` can't track that the serialized pointer is a reference to the object.

Comment: Use [`uintptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) if you want to store a pointer in an integer instead.

Comment: Why do you need serialisation? Threads share memory; why not just pass the shared pointer?

Comment: Yes I agree. I left out some details here. The objPtr is being stored in a map maintained in thread 1. And thread 2 stores/maintains the shared_ptr in a different data structure. So the object shouldn't be getting destroyed (although I'll verify through the debugger).

Comment: @AndrewP Note that you are passing a pointer to the `shared_ptr<T>` and not the `T` so the actual `shared_ptr` needs to still be alive. Make sure your container isn't invalidating it's iterators and that it isn't being moved.

Comment: Could you just for testing store objPtr in Thread 1 in a static variable (so that it does not get destroyed)? So that serialzedPtr points to that static variable?

Comment: Yes, you do need to synchronize access to the `shared_ptr` if it can be modified by any thread after it's shared between two or more threads.

Comment: @eerorika, The messaging mechanism that I cooked up is used for passing messages between computers via TCP/IP and between threads colocated on the same processor. I'd prefer to using this messaging approach from an architectural standpoint but if I can't get it working I might eventually forgo using it for this data transfer.

Comment: Are both threads in the same process?

Comment: @Sebastian If not then it would never work. It appears to work most of the time.

Comment: @Francois Andrieux & Sebastian, your suggestions seems to be correct. The manner in which I'm storing the shared_ptr's in the map must be wrong for when I store them in a static array I no longer crash.

Comment: @AndrewP The issue is that you are passing the thread the address of a temporary object allocated on the stack. See my answer.

Comment: @AndrewP Could you add that objPtr is not a local stack-stored variable in the question?
This would also help people looking for similar problems/solutions

Comment: @AndrewP, you said "The messaging mechanism that I cooked up is used for passing messages between computers via TCP/IP and between threads colocated on the same processor.". -- are thread1 and thread2 from the same process? If thread1 and thread2 running on different hosts, it makes no sense for thread2 to hold a reference to a memory address on a remote host.

Comment: @SPD Yes, thread1 and thread2 are always on the same process. And if they weren't (due to a misconfiguration or something), I have checks in place that would prevent the message from being sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shared_ptr` automatically increases and decreases its internally-stored reference count when you copy it (using the assignment `operator=`), and - importantly - when a `shared_ptr` is destroyed (by going out of scope).  Your approach for transmitting a pointer-to-shared-pointer is fundamentally flawed in the code above, because you are transmitting the *address* of a temporary shared pointer, but not the *ownership or lifespan*.  The `shared_ptr` - which is still owned by Thread A - might go out of scope and be destroyed before Thread B can use it.

In order to *transfer ownership* of a shared_ptr instance, I would suggest creating a heap-allocated/dynamic `shared_ptr` for transfer. This can be accomplished using `new` or (even better) `make_unique`.  Using a unique_ptr (i.e.: `unique_ptr<shared_ptr<ObjectClass>>`), you would use the 'release' method, before passing the pointer across the thread barrier in your message.

Thread A:

```
auto sharedPtr = std::make_shared<ObjectClass>();

// This line creates a heap-allocated copy of a 
// shared_ptr (incrementing reference count)
// And places ownership inside a unique_ptr
auto sharedPtrDynamicCopy = std::make_unique<decltype(sharedPtr)>(sharedPtr);

// This 'releases' ownership of the heap-allocated shared_ptr,
// returning a raw pointer; it is now a potential
// memory leak!!!  It must be 'captured' in Thread B.
auto rawPtrToPass = sharedPtrDynamicCopy.release();
```

Thread B:

```
// Here, we immediately 'capture' the raw pointer back
// inside a unique_ptr, closing the loop on the potential
// memory leak
auto sharedPtrDynamicCopy = unique_ptr<shared_ptr<ObjectClass>>(rawPtrFromThreadA);

// Now we can make a copy of the shared_ptr, if we like.
// This sharedCopy will live on, even after recvdPtr goes
// out of scope.
auto sharedCopy = *sharedPtrDynamicCopy;
```

You could perhaps shorten this further by simply 'new'-ing a raw `shared_ptr` instead of capturing it inside a `unique_ptr<shared_ptr<T>>`, but I personally prefer this approach since it has clear "capture" and "release" semantics for the pointer-in-flight.

Comment: Assuming thread1 and thread2 are from the same process (OP's requirement of " passing messages between computers via TCP/IP" makes no sense ...), why can't thread2 have a shared_ptr created from sharedPtr created in thread1 directly?

Answer (score 2):

Your code sends the address of a temporary shared pointer from one thread to another. You create `objPtr` as an object on the stack and you pass the address of `objPtr` (not the object's address!) to the thread.

That is not what you want to do. You have two sane choices:

1. Send the address of the *object* from one thread to the other and ensure that at least one shared pointer to the object exists at all times (as you claim your code already does). This is a scary fix because it doesn't ensure the object's lifetime is sufficient.
2. Use `new` to dynamically allocated an additional shared pointer to the object and pass the pointer to that shared pointer to the thread. Have the thread `delete` the shared pointer when it's done with the object. This is probably the simplest fix that ensures the object's lifetime is sufficient.

A general pattern for passing objects to threads is to create a class or structure that carries all the information you want to pass to the thread. Before you create the thread, use `new` to create a new instance of the structure and fill it in as needed. Then pass the address of that structure to the thread. When the thread is done with the structure, have the thread use `delete` to free the structure. You can use this to pass any collection of objects or data to a thread. In this case, you want to pass an actual `shared_ptr` to the thread -- not the address of one.

Comment: In a world where unique_ptr and shared_ptr exist, we try to avoid using new and delete wherever possible.  Prefer a unique_ptr with 'release,' as this conveys capture and transfer semantics.

Comment: @BTownTKD Creating a `unique_ptr` just to immediately call `release` on it seems quite pointless. And dealing with a `unique_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` just seems a bit gross to me.

Comment: I guess, if expressive code is pointless...?  See my answer for how the unique_ptr is created.

Comment: I fail to see how two lines of code that do the exact equivalent of `new` is more expressive than `new`.

Comment: Additionally: the first option you provided is simply bad advice. You can't pass the address of the object and have it owned by two separate shared_ptrs.  It will certainly result in double-delete.

Comment: @BTownTKD My first example doesn't involve more than one shared pointer other than to note that at least one `shared_ptr` must exist. It just involves passing the address of the object itself between threads.

Comment: You're wrong; creating a second shared pointer from a *raw pointer already owned by a shared pointer* will result in two separate reference counts and two deletes.

Comment: @BTownTKD Right. Nowhere did I suggest that anyone do that. I clarified to make clear that he claims his code already does that and this is not a recommended change.

Comment: I think some clarifications and example code in your answer would benefit the OP then.